# How to loop through children and grandchildren in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to find a way to do `\App\Goal::find(1)->children` and get returned all children, and childrens children.

With the database pasted below I want
`\App\Goal::find(1)->children`
to return 
`2, 4 and 5`. Currently I can only do `\App\Goal::find(1)->goals`, which returns only `2 and 4`

I have a database like this:

```
id          user_id     goal_id     objective
1            1             NULL        Get rich
2            1              1          Save $5
3            1              NULL       Learn to cook
4            1              1          Save $10,000
5            1              4          Buy stocks
6            1              5          Buy 5x Intel
7            1              5          Buy 5x AMD
```

How would you go about creating the children() function in the Goal model?

Please ask if any important info is missing from this

Edit:

Goal.php:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToUser(User::class);
}

public function goals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Goal::class, 'goal_id')
}
```

When I run \App\Goals::find(1)->goals in the GoalController it returns the children of itself (with id 2 and 4 from the example db table), but not its grandchildren...

ID 5 from the example table has a parent of id 4, which itself has a parent id of 1.

So how could I get `\App\Goal::find(1)->children` or `\App\Goal::find(1)->goals` to return its grandchildren, and their children etc?

Comment: Can you show with an array what you expect to get as result?
Is not very clear what you what to get and which params are you passing

Comment: Yeah sorry, updated it a bit now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming the table you've posted is the `goals` table, related to `App\Goal`...

If you have these two relationships set up on the model:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Goal::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function childrenRecursive()
{
    return $this->children()->with('children');
}
```

You can call `Goal::with('childrenRecursive')->get()` which will return a nested collection of all the children and children's children.

If you'd like all of the children in a flat array, you could do something like this:

```
public function getFamilyAttribute()
{
    $family = collect([]);
    $children = $this->children;
    while (!is_null($children )) {
        $family->push($children);
        $children = $children->children;
    }
    return $family;
}
```

Comment: We're getting close! It seems it does not get grandchildrens children, though? I updated my post and example table with more info

Comment: Figured it out. Whatever I did my solution is Goal::find(1)->goals()->with('recursiveChildren')->get();

Comment: When I try to run the getFamilyAttribute function I get an error Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\GoalController::$children.

Any idea why?